# C++ macros explanation

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

Can somebody explain the following code please?

```
#if 1

// loop type
#define FOR_IS_FASTER 1
#define WHILE_IS_FASTER 0
// indexing type
#define PREINCREMENT_IS_FASTER 1
#define POSTINCREMENT_IS_FASTER 0

#else

// loop type
#define FOR_IS_FASTER 1
#define WHILE_IS_FASTER 0
// indexing type
#define PREINCREMENT_IS_FASTER 0
#define POSTINCREMENT_IS_FASTER 1

#endif


#if PREINCREMENT_IS_FASTER
#define ZXP(z) (*++(z))
#define ZX(z) (*(z))
#define PZ(z) (++(z))
#define ZP(z) (z)
#define ZOFF (1)
#elif POSTINCREMENT_IS_FASTER
#define ZXP(z) (*(z)++)
#define ZX(z) (*(z))
#define PZ(z) (z)
#define ZP(z) ((z)++)
#define ZOFF (0)
#endif
```

I can understand what the functions are doing but for example
how does the pre-processor  choose which ZXP will be execute if we call it later?
What do the 1 and 0 stand for?

Comment: It is all probably done for code obfuscation. You are not supposed to understand any of it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `#if 1` triggers the first group of `#define`s, which set PREINCREMENT_IS_FASTER to 1. Because of this, `#if PREINCREMENT_IS_FASTER` triggers the first `#define ZXP...`.

There is nothing exceptional about 1 and 0 in this context. The `#if` preprocessor directive succeeds if its argument is non-zero.

You can switch to the alternate form by changing the `#if 1` at the top of the file with `#if 0`. (Thank you @rabidmachine for the tip.)

Comment: thanks!
so whats the need to have both of them if we always know that we will execute the first ZXP?

Comment: @rabidmachine: You can switch to use the other set by changing the first line to `#if 0`

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably inclined to agree with UncleBens and suggest that it's done so that you don't understand it, because the whole lot is totally useless.